# Understanding the options in a handlebars #view helper for Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

This is for Ember.JS version 1.11

I've just started learning Ember and have been tasked with maintaining an existing project. I can see code in many of my handlebars files that looks like this:

```
 {{#each myitem in controller.mylist}}
    {{#view "loading" story=myitem}}
       {{myitem.name}}<br>
    {{/view}}
 {{/each}}
```

I can see from this that:

1. Ember will iterate over the objects in the `mylist` list property of the associated controller.
2. For each item visited (here called `myitem`) it will render its `name` property followed by a linebreak
3. Each item will be rendered using an Ember View called `App.LoadingView`. This is by virtue of Ember's automatic mapping of the the first parameter of the `#view` helper, in this case `"loading"`, to the identifier of the view constructor.

I grok-ed this with the help of the handlebars [documentation](http://www.ember-doc.com/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_view). However I'm puzzled by the second parameter to the `#view` helper, being `story=myitem`. The [documentation](http://www.ember-doc.com/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_view) says:

> `{{view}}` inserts a new instance of an `Ember.View` into a template
>   passing its options to the `Ember.View`'s `create` method and using the
>   supplied block as the view's own template.

So `story=myitem` appears to be an "option" that is passed to the view controller, which in my code looks like this:

```
  App.LoadingView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
      this.$().parents().children(".loading").fadeOut(1500);
      this.$().hide().delay(600).fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
```

I can't seen any reference to `story` in this constructor, and it does not seem to be a standard `#view` option.

I also did a global text search in my project for "story" and the only place it appears is in the handlebars files.

So where is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App.LoadingView` is a class, not an instance.  When Ember needs to create instances of it, it will call create on the instance and pass in the parameters.

In your case, the code corresponding to your template would look something like this:

```
var j = App.LoadingView.create({
  story: myItem
});
```

`story` will end up being a property that just lives right on the loading view instance.

Comment: You're right I was getting the class definition confused with the constructor. I can't find the constructor anywhere in my project. In fact the only place `App.LoadingView` appears is in the class definition. Could it be that Ember is automatically calling the constructor? In which case what would be the purpose of the `story` option?

Comment: Ember is definitely calling the create method on its own, when you asked for an instance of `loading` view to be inserted.  Their might be a loading template (associated by name) that uses `story` within it.

Comment: Thanks, it's much clearer now. However there doesn't appear to be a "Loading" template in my project, and the only place that the string "story" appears is in a number of `#view` helpers like the one shown in my question above. I guess it's possible that it's no longer used in this particular application.